# How multiple accounts can sign transaction in PDA CPI

Tags: pda, anchor-lang, cpi

How can multiple accounts can sign transaction along with PDA ?

In PDA based CPI in which PDA signs transactions, how can we use multiple accounts as a signers ?

I have to create an account in callee program using CPI, here I have to pass new account address or public key by signing transaction to callee program.

**Callee Program**

```
#[program]
mod callee {
    use super::*;

    // I want to call this method using cpi in which pda should be signer.
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.new_account.data = data;
        msg!("Changed data to: {}!", data);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64
}
```

**Caller Program**

```
#[constant]
const USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS: &[u8] = b"USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS";

#[program]
pub mod caller {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_user_account(ctx: Context<CreateUserAccount>) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.user_account.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("user_account").unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn invoke_transaction<'info>(
        ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, InvokeTransaction<'info>>,
        data: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // Am i doing any mistake here
        let ix = solana_program::instruction::Instruction {
            program_id: ctx.accounts.program_to_be_called.key(),
            accounts: vec![
                AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.new_account.key(), true),
                AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.user_account.key(), true),
                AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.system_program.key(), false),
            ],
            data,
        };

        solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &ix,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.new_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.user_account.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[
                USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS,
                ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref(),
                &[ctx.accounts.user_account.bump],
            ]],
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateUserAccount<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer=signer,
        space= 8 + std::mem::size_of::<UserAccount>(),
        seeds=[USER_ACCOUNT_SEEDS,signer.key().as_ref()],
    bump)]
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct UserAccount {
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InvokeTransaction<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,

    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    pub program_to_be_called: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub new_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

- **Error i am getting** Invalid program argument.
- **Note**:- When i use signer of invoke_transaction as a signer in cpi this code works fine, but when i use user_account (pda) as a signer i gets above given error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple addresses to sign a CPI. Here's how you will do it:

```
invoke_signed(
        &instruction,
        accounts,
        &[&["First addresses seed"],
          &["Second addresses first seed", "Second addresses second seed"]],
    )?;
```

Source: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#program-signed-accounts

---

If the CPI instruction requires a non-PDA signer, add the signature for such signer in your original transaction. No adjustments needed at the program level.

Comment: This is useful when all signers are PDA address, what to do when other signers are not PDA addresses.

Comment: In such case, just sign your original transaction with the new account. No adjustment is needed at the program level. The answer is edited to reflect the fact.

Comment: I had also tried this, can you please share any example Or demo code with me ?

Comment: Can you share your callee program? I will explain the caller program's instruction and the client side code on the basis of that.

Comment: I have edited question and added my callee and caller program code.

Comment: Answered in the other question thread.